# Unable to Login after updating a Path Variable

Tags: bash

I wanted to add a path to my flutter SDK in my Ubuntu. So I added export PATH= "$PATH: $HOME/Documents/Dev/App_Dev/flutter/bin" in the .bashrc file. After that whenever I started the terminal, it showed some path and "not a valid identifier" was written and no terminal commands are working.

Then I restarted my laptop, and now I am not able to login even after entering the correct password.

Comment: You need to remove the space after the `=` sign. Are you able to log in to a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2 for example)?

Comment: No, I am not able to login. I tried the recovery mode, but there the .bashrc file is perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you look at the right `.bashrc` (i.e. your user's file, rather than the `root` user's)?

Comment: I could access only root user's file. How to access the other?

Comment: something like `/bin/nano /home/<username>/.bashrc` where `<username>` is replaced by your actual username

Comment: ohk...will try. Thank You